# How to get emacs terminal theme for emacs app

Tags: mac, emacs, osx-mountain-lion, color-theme

This may be a weird one. I have read questions on how to get the terminal to display better colors but I like the colors that emacs uses in my terminal (256 colors, Mac OS X). I am a complete noob in a ll of this, so I am pasting what I think may be relevant from my init.el file below.

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-names-vector ["#242424" "#e5786d" "#95e454" "#cae682" "#8ac6f2" "#333366" "#ccaa8f" "#f6f3e8"]))
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me about a theme that would replicate emacs colors from the terminal in the EMACS app (for those that don't know what an app is, its the commonly used word for programs in the application folder on OS X).

**EDIT:**

This is what it looks like on my terminal:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Seems like this simple question is not so simple to understand. Let me try it again.

I have Emacs on my OS X that runs on the terminal. I also have an Emacs GUI that runs as an application. I like the way Emacs looks on my terminal (pictured above) and I would like the GUI Emacs to look like it. All I need is the name of a theme that would make my Emacs GUI look  like it does on my terminal.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: Anyone at all? Or is this not an answerable question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web for days on end, I found the theme that was close enough to what I was looking for. Its called ir-black and can be found here:

https://github.com/jmdeldin/ir-black-theme.el

I had to change some colors to make it look exactly as I wanted it to look. I'm going to paste the color settings here for anyone else to copy, if they are interested.

```
(let ((*background-color*   "#000000")
      (*brown*              "#E64")
      (*comments*           "#FF0000")
      (*constant*           "#008080")
      (*current-line*       "#1A1D2B")
      (*cursor-block*       "#FFA560")
      (*cursor-underscore*  "#8888AA")
      (*keywords*           "#CC33CC")
      (*light-purple*       "#FFCCFF")
      (*line-number*        "#111")
      (*method-declaration* "#3300CC")
      (*mode-line-bg*       "#202020")
      (*mode-line-fg*       "#FFA560")
      (*normal*             "#F6F3E8")
      (*number*             "#FF73FD")
      (*operators*          "#228B22")
      (*red*                "#FF6C60")
      (*red-light*          "#FFB6B0")
      (*regexp*             "#E9C")
      (*regexp-alternate*   "#FF0")
      (*regexp-alternate-2* "#B18A3D")
      (*search-selection*   "#2F2F00")
      (*string*             "#8B008B")
      (*string-inner*       "#00A0A0")
      (*variable*           "#C76114")
      (*visual-selection*   "#FFA560"))
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.byteengine.net/custom-colors-in-snow-leopard-terminal-64-bit has a method to customize Terminal colors in OSX Snow Leopard using the [TerminalColours](https://github.com/timmfin/terminalcolours) plugin; I don't know if these solutions would work in Mountain Lion (and I only have SL to test, sorry!)

> replicate emacs colors from the terminal in the app.

By "the app", you mean Terminal, right? It's not completely clear what you're trying to customize.

Comment: no, by app I mean the Emacs app in the Applications folder. I will edit the question but I thought it was clear enough the question wasn't about the Terminal but about Emacs (hence the tags).

Comment: THere are standalone Emacs GUI programs for Mac OS X, similar to GVim.

Comment: Ohh, got it, sorry!